# Template class copy constructor parameter with or without template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, methods, constructor

Hi is the following two are equivalent:

```
template<class T>
class name {
public:
    name() {/*...*/}
    name(name const &o) {/*...*/} // WITHOUT TEMPLATE ARGUMENT
    /*...*/
};
```

---

```
template<class T>
class name {
public:
    name() {/*...*/}
    name(name<T> const &o) {/*...*/} // WITH TEMPLATE ARGUMENT SPECIFIED
    /*...*/
};
```

So my question is this: Do I have to write *classname* **with** or **without** the template argument list in the copy constructor or not? If I don't write the template arguments does it mean that then other versions (with different template argument) can be passed to the copy constructor?

So if I want to achive that from the class *A* with template argument e.g.: *int*, the copy constructor of it only accept *A* with the **same** template argument (in our example: *int*), do I have to put the template arguments (< T, K, ...>) there?

Comment: The two you show are equivalent.

Comment: [Here](https://ideone.com/lAo948) you can see they are the same.

Comment: @NathanOliver just to confirm: from the [example](https://ideone.com/lAo948) you linked. You mean that: as a consequence that the two specifications - with and without `<T>` - are (treated as) the same, they cannot be overlaoded, right? Otherwise - if they weren't actually the same - they could have been overloaded. Did I understand it correctly? Thanks

Comment: @GabrielePompa Yes.  They are the same thing so you get a compiler error if you use both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using class name in a class template without template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891207/using-class-name-in-a-class-template-without-template-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I have to write classname with or without the template argument list in the copy constructor or not?

They are equivalent. Within the template's scope, `name` is the *injected class name*, denoting the class `name<T>`. It can also be used as the template name, if you specify template arguments.

> If I don't write the template arguments does it mean that then other versions (with different template argument) can be passed to the copy constructor?

No, without arguments it specifically denotes `name<T>`. To allow conversion from other specialisations, you'd need a constructor template:

```
template <typename T2> name(name<T2> const & other);
```

Note that this won't act as a copy constructor: you'll need to declare that separately if you don't want the implicitly generated one.

> So if I want to achive that [...] it only accept A with the same template argument [...], do I have to put the template arguments (< T, K, ...>) there?

No, what you have is fine in that case.

Comment: this helps, thanks. Can you maybe provide some reference?

Answer (score 2):

inside the template definition, `name` is a shorthand for `name<T>`
( see §14.6.1 )