# Best way define function that returns instance of or reference to template object

Tags: c++, templates

In the below example class, what is the difference between the two assignment operator definitions? Is there any? They both appear to compile/behave the same way.

```
template <typename T>
struct S
{
    T internal;
    //#1
    S& operator= (const T& other)
    {
        internal = other;
        return *this;
    }

    //#2
    S<T>& operator= (const T& other)
    {
        internal = other;
        return *this;
    }
}
```

A more generalalized question could be something along the lines of "do you have to specify template specialization type when returning (references/pointers to) templated objects? Or does the compiler automatically supply the specialization type if you do not specify it?"

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891207/using-class-name-in-a-class-template-without-template-parameters

Comment: @Rakete1111 think that basically answers it, my google-fu was insufficient to find that question. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! I'll mark it as dupe then.

Comment: By the way, your above code is missing return statement: `return *this;`.

Comment: “Or does the compiler automatically supply the specialization type if you do not specify it?” A rule of thump in C++, never assume the compiler will do “wonders” behind the scene. If your code requires that specialization type, then it’s better you explicitly declare it. I know that might not answer your question, but just a small comment in mind.