# How to make class template argument deduction work inside the class itself?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction, class-template

A MCVE:

```
template <typename T>
struct S
{
  S(T) {
      S s{nullptr}; // expect S<std::nullptr_t>, but it is S<T> 
  };
};

int main()
{
  S{42};
}
```

Here I expect the type of `s` to be deduced to `S<std::nullptr_t>`, but [the type name `S` is  treated as an injected-class-name, which refers to `S<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891207/using-class-name-in-a-class-template-without-template-parameters), hence [an error](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Jos6ld).

How can I make class template argument deduction work here?