# Is having a declaration Stack<T>(); for the default ctor valid inside a class template

Tags: c++, templates, class-template, errata

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71971376/15545927) to a question on SO related to the declaration for a default constructor of a class template that said that the following code is not valid C++ due to [CWG1435](https://wg21.link/CWG1435):

```
template <class T> class Stack {
public:
  Stack<T>(); //IS THIS VALID?
};
```

---

While another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970724/17881448) said that the above example is valid C++. There are 2 sources for the claim that the above example is valid:

1. [Injected class names](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name#In_class_template):

> Otherwise, it is treated as a type-name, and is equivalent to the template-name followed by the template-parameters of the class template enclosed in <>

2. In a [CppCon conference](https://youtu.be/LMP_sxOaz6g?list=PLpHxZMy35Lo1255K3eSmjd161ra4vSnFT&t=1519) **Dan Saks** basically showed a very similar example.

So as we can see the two linked answers make opposite claims and i don't know which one is correct. So **my question is** which of the two answers is correct. That is, is the declaration `Stack<T>();` valid C++ or not.

PS: I am asking my question for Modern C++ meaning from C++11 & onwards.

Comment: I would expect the question to ask the opposite, if `Stack();` was valid. Which is is, and it will be equivalent to `Stack<T>();`, which is what you have written in the question (and therefore needs to be valid).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shown snippet is valid for Pre-C++20 but not valid from C++20 & onwards as explained below.

##### Pre-C++20

From [class.ctor#1.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.ctor#1.2):

> **1** -- Constructors do not have names. In a declaration of a constructor, the declarator is a function declarator of the form:
>
> `ptr-declarator ( parameter-declaration-clause ) noexcept-specifieropt attribute-specifier-seqopt`
>
> where the ptr-declarator consists solely of an **id-expression**, an optional attribute-specifier-seq, and optional surrounding parentheses, and the id-expression has one of the following forms:
>
> **1.2** -- in a member-declaration that belongs to the member-specification of a class template but is not a friend declaration, the **id-expression is a class-name that names the current instantiation of the immediately-enclosing class template**; or

(end quote)

This means that in C++17, we are allowed to use `Stack<T>();` as the constructor declaration.

##### C++20

From [class.ctor#1.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.ctor#1.1):

> **1** -- A constructor is introduced by a declaration whose declarator is a function declarator ([dcl.fct]) of the form:
> `ptr-declarator ( parameter-declaration-clause ) noexcept-specifieropt attribute-specifier-seqopt`
>
> where the ptr-declarator consists solely of an id-expression, an optional attribute-specifier-seq, and optional surrounding parentheses, and the id-expression has one of the following forms:
>
> **1.1** -- in a member-declaration that belongs to the member-specification of a class or class template but is not a friend declaration ([class.friend]), the **id-expression is the injected-class-name ([class.pre]) of the immediately-enclosing entity** or

So as we can see, the *injected class name*(which is `Stack` and not `Stack<T>` in your example) is needed for declaring the ctor of a class template.

This means that your given code is not valid for C++20.

---

The same is also mentioned at [diff.cpp17.class#2](https://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp17.class#2):

> **Affected subclauses**: [class.ctor] and [class.dtor]
>
> **Change**: A simple-template-id is no longer valid as the declarator-id of a constructor or destructor.
>
> **Rationale**: Remove potentially error-prone option for redundancy.
>
> **Effect on original feature**: Valid C++ 2017 code may fail to compile in this revision of C++.
> For example:
>
> ```
> template<class T>
> struct A {
>   A<T>();           // error: simple-template-id not allowed for constructor
>   A(int);           // OK, injected-class-name used
>   ~A<T>();          // error: simple-template-id not allowed for destructor
> };
> ```

Comment: Is `Stack<T>` an id-expression?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, `Stack<T>` is a template-id which is an unqualified-id and so an id-expression.

Answer (score 5):

Your example has an *unqualified-id* which is a *template-id*.  This is not permitted under [the latest wording](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#general-1), the constructor must be introduced by its *injected-class-name*.

Your quote about the equivalence between *injected-class-name* and *template-name* followed by template parameters doesn't apply here, because the identifier here isn't a type name, it is a constructor declaration.

This has definitely changed since C++11.