# Backward compatibility of template code in g++

Tags: c++, g++, backwards-compatibility

`g++` 11.3.0 can't compile this code:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo<T>() {}
};
```

Error is

```
expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
```

One way to fix it is correcting `Foo<T>` to `Foo` because modern versions of `g++` can understand template class methods inside the class without a template parameter.

But code like this could be compiled in earlier versions of `g++`.

Manual code fixing is an inconvenient way because some open source dependencies like websocketcpp contain plenty of code like this, it's very inconvenient to make your own forks and fix all code.

So, I suggest there is a flag or some pragma in `g++` which may help to work around this problem. Is there some work around here without code fixing?

Comment: `Foo<T>()` is ill-formed. Replace it with `Foo()`. See [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71972000/is-having-a-declaration-stackt-for-the-default-ctor-valid-inside-a-class-te).

Comment: I think your only option is probably to either not compile with c++20 or to submit an issue (or even better a pull request) to the relevant projects to get them to fix their code

Comment: The flag is `-std` with any C++ version before C++20 as argument. This is an intentional backwards-compatibility breaking change and noted as such in the C++20 standard, see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/diff.cpp17.class#2 for the post-C++20 draft. "_because moders versions of g++ can understand template class methods inside the class without a template parameter._": It was always possible to do it that way in standard C++. So only something pre-standard could be an issue with modified code, but then you wouldn't need to compile for C++20 anyway.

Comment: No option to disable this was added when it was implemented in gcc https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blobdiff;f=gcc/cp/parser.c;h=a8082d39aca25b51d261fb98f2d1e7e943a6673d;hp=a6a5d975af3edfe8c5cc7ff1b39280c37e463dbc;hb=4b38d56dbac6742b038551a36ec80200313123a1;hpb=38a4db21e12816c674406f33d8bc4d064d4211d7

Comment: I reopened the question, because OP is _not_ asking for how to fix the code, but how to work around the incompatible change. I think that is not covered in the other question.

Comment: This has already been fixed for websocketpp at least https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/commit/3197a520eb4c1e4754860441918a5930160373eb