# template class constructor declaration followed by template parameters like classA<Type>(...)

Tags: c++, c++-templates

I have a legacy template class code which has been used for years.
It has the following form for instance

```
template<typename Type>
class MyTemplateClass
{
    public:
        MyTemplateClass<Type>()
        {}
};

int main()
{
    MyTemplateClass<double> myclass;

}
```

I understand that the above expression is not valid any more from C++20  thanks to the [link][1]

What I want to know now is that what was the difference by writting

```
MyTemplateClass<Type>()
```

and

```
MyTemplateClass()
```

before c++20 since those two constructor declarations seem do the same thing.

Comment: This is because in C++20, `MyTemplateClass<Type>()` is invalid. Replace it with `MyTemplateClass()` See [Is having a declaration Stack<T>(); for the default ctor valid inside a class template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71972000/is-having-a-declaration-stackt-for-the-default-ctor-valid-inside-a-class-te)

Comment: *"I want to know now is that what was the difference..."* This is already well explained in the dupe. In particular, Pre-c++20 they were equivalent ways of writing the ctor/dtor declaration but post-c++20, the `classname<T>` is invalid as only injected-class-name is allowed in writing the declarations for ctor/dtor.

Comment: @user12002570, So if I understand you correctly, there were two kinds of ways in ctor/dtor declaration which were equivalent each other. Since post c++20, there is only a single way in ctor/dtor declaration.

Comment: Yes exactly. C++20 discarded the use of `classname<T>` like in your example because `classname<T>` is not an injected-class-name.

Comment: @user12002570 Thank you for enlightening me. I feel much more informed now.