# How to define a seperate implementation of a template class constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, declaration, definition

I am working with an old code in C++ that uses a custom implementation of a matrix class.

The matrix is class is implemented as a template class. The declaration looks like this

```
/**********************************************************************/
/*** TMatrix private **************************************************/
/**********************************************************************/
//
template <class X> class TMatrix {

private :

long min_adr_row; 
long max_adr_row; 


/**********************************************************************/
/*** TMatrix public ***************************************************/
/**********************************************************************/
//
public:
   
long     row;                        
long     col;                        

X     **data;                        


 TMatrix<X> (const long & m = 0,              /*** Konstruktor      ***/
             const long & n = 0);
 TMatrix<X> (const TMatrix<X> & A);           /*** Copy-Konstruktor ***/
~TMatrix<X> (void);                           /*** Destruktor       ***/


/**********************************************************************/
/*** overloaded operators *******************************************/
/**********************************************************************/
//
X *        & operator [] (const long & index)   const; /*** []      ***/
TMatrix<X> & operator =  (const TMatrix<X> & A);       /***  =      ***/

TMatrix<X>   operator +  (const TMatrix<X> & A) const; /*** C = A+B ***/
TMatrix<X>   operator -  (const TMatrix<X> & A) const; /*** C = A-B ***/
TMatrix<X>   operator *  (const TMatrix<X> & A) const; /*** C = A*B ***/

TMatrix<X> & operator += (const TMatrix<X> & A);       /*** B = B+A ***/
TMatrix<X> & operator -= (const TMatrix<X> & A);       /*** B = B-A ***/
TMatrix<X> & operator *= (const TMatrix<X> & A);       /*** B = B*A ***/

TMatrix<X>   operator *  (const double a)       const; /*** B = A*a ***/
int          operator == (const TMatrix<X> & A) const; /*** B == A  ***/

// ... other methods

};
```

This code is contained in the header file TMatrix.h.

The implementations are contained in the same header file. I am getting an error in the definition of the first constructor that currently looks like this:

```
template <class X> TMatrix<X>::TMatrix<X>(const long & m, const long & n) {


// .. do stuff where 'data' and 'X' are used


return;
}
```

The project previously ran with C++ 11 where that code compiled without errors.

However with newer C++ versions this code throws various errors (does not compile) depending on the different versions.

For example under C++ 14 I am getting the compiler error C2988 unrecognizable template declaration/definition.

I suspect that there is something inherently wrong with the definition of this constructor and/or possibly with the declaration of the class itself.

I tried to replace the first line of the definition with

`template <class X> TMatrix(const long & m, const long & n) {`

which seems more logical to me but it gives the Syntax error: "deduction guide cannot be defined".

I also don't understand why the template keyword has to be used in the constructor definition but not in its declaration within the class.

I am considering now to simply replace this template constructor with two separate "normal" constructors for int and double which are the only types that this class is being used with in the code. But I still want to understand what caused this error and why it works fine in C++ 11.

Hope someone can help, thanks.

Comment: If you're asking about build errors, then copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build-log into your question. And try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: You need to remove the `<X>` from `TMatrix<X>` when defining/declaring the  constructor and destructor inside the class as well as outside the class. See dupe: [Is having a declaration Stack<T>(); for the default ctor valid inside a class template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71972000/is-having-a-declaration-stackt-for-the-default-ctor-valid-inside-a-class-te). After you do this(what I said above), the program will [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/ME6brK4ev)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @user12002570. Now there is another issue though. I edited the original question.

Comment: @ST11280709 You're welcome. I would suggest asking a new separate question for your follow up question instead of editing your question to show a new problem. Feel free to create a new question with the new issue.

Answer (score 0):

The definition for the constructor should only have template arguments on the part before the double colon:

```
template <class X> 
TMatrix<X>::TMatrix(const long & m, const long & n) {
    // .. do stuff where 'data' and 'X' are used
    return;
}
```

Clang tells you this in its error:

```
<source>:49:32: error: out-of-line constructor for 'TMatrix' cannot have template arguments
   49 | template <class X> TMatrix<X>::TMatrix<X>(const long & m, const long & n) {
      |
```

Comment: Actually, this also applies when defining/declaring constructor/destrutor inside the class. See the dupe. Even though some compiler still accept `~TMatrix<X> (void);` inside the class, the program is ill-formed in C++20 as explained in the duplicate.