# Explicitly deleted function not work in c++20

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++17, c++20

While implementing some code of singleton, I need to delete the default constructor, which like below.

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass{
public:
MyClass<T>()=delete;
}
```

this will return a compiler error:
expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token

Code like this:
https://godbolt.org/z/bPzqfPvb1

However, this is fine with gcc-9 and c++-17, but not works in gcc-13 and c++-20. As I am new to this, I have no idea about which went wrong.

It is ok for lower c++ std, but I do not find some related docs to explain this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this has changed between the C++17 and C++20 standard, but I know that the `<T>` part isn't needed. `Myclass() = delete;` is just fine.

Comment: I believe the extra `<T>` got banned in C++20.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The extra `<T>` makes the program ill-formed in C++20. [Is having a declaration Stack<T>(); for the default ctor valid inside a class template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71972000/is-having-a-declaration-stackt-for-the-default-ctor-valid-inside-a-class-te)

Comment: btw , `While implementing some code of singleton, I need to delete the default constructor` you dont really need this. You will need a constructor to create an instances (singleton? ok, you need to construct 1 instance). And once you do declare a non-default constructor there will be no default constructor

Comment: Side note : Step 1, avoid singletons. Step2. If you still think you need a singletone then use a meyer's singleton . The basic pattern for Meyer's singleton: `auto& GetInstance() { static ClassT singleton{args...}; return singleton; };`.  I also find it a bit strange to have a singleton with only a non-default constructor.