# How to fix C++20 error: 'expected unqualified-id before ‘const’' in templated class

Tags: c++, c++20

We have a C++ class called **Matrix** that compiles fine in C++17 but fails to build in C++20. I understand that the reason is https://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp17.class#2 and I think that the fix is to replace the copy constructor with a template specialization, but I don't know how to do this.

Compiler is **gcc 11.4.0**.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <complex>

class MatrixBase
{
public:
    MatrixBase() : m_numRows(0), m_numCols(0) {}
    MatrixBase( const MatrixBase& a_X ) : m_numRows(a_X.m_numRows), m_numCols(a_X.m_numCols) {}
    virtual ~MatrixBase() {}   

protected:
    unsigned m_numRows;
    unsigned m_numCols;
};

// Matrix class
template<class T> class Matrix : public MatrixBase
{
public:
    //  Constructors without initialising data
    Matrix();
    Matrix( unsigned a_numRows, unsigned a_numCols );

    //  Constructor for creating a 1-by-1 matrix from a scalar
    Matrix( const T& a_val );

    //  Copy constructor
    Matrix( const Matrix& a_X ); 

    //  Create a matrix from a matrix of another data type
    template<class T1> Matrix<T>( const Matrix<T1>& a_X )     //  <-- LINE 31
    {
    }

    virtual ~Matrix() {}   

protected:
    std::vector<T> m_data;
};

// Constructor with initialising data
template<class T> Matrix<T>::Matrix( const T& a_val ) : MatrixBase()
{
}

typedef Matrix<double> RealMatrix;
typedef Matrix< std::complex<double> > ComplexMatrix;

int main()
{
    RealMatrix    R(1.0);
    ComplexMatrix C(R);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
main.cpp:31:35: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
   31 |     template<class T1> Matrix<T>( const Matrix<T1>& a_X )
```

Please suggest a fix.

Comment: Your constructor syntax is wrong - it's just `Matrix`, not `Matrix<T>`.

Comment: This is valid in c++17 but not in c++20. See [Is having a declaration Stack<T>(); for the default ctor valid inside a class template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71981884/12002570). Just change `template<class T1> Matrix<T>` to `template<class T1> Matrix`.